# How to Click an Element inside a p-dropdown tag using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, select, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

```
<p-dropdown _ngcontent-c16="" autofocus="" placeholder="Select Quota" class="ng-tns-c13-11 ui-inputwrapper-filled ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <div class="ng-tns-c13-11 ui-dropdown ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="width: 234px;">
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible ng-tns-c13-11 ng-star-inserted">
    <select class="ng-tns-c13-11" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" aria-label="A">
      <option class="ng-tns-c13-11 ng-star-inserted">Select</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c13-11 ng-star-inserted" value="GN">A</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c13-11 ng-star-inserted" value="SS">B</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c13-11 ng-star-inserted" value="LD">C</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c13-11 ng-star-inserted" value="HP">D</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c13-11 ng-star-inserted" value="TQ">E</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c13-11 ng-star-inserted" value="PT">F</option>
      <!----></select>
    </div>
```

I need to select a value inside the drop down
the xpath I tried using is :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@value='LD']").click()
```

But that says element not found...What other expression can be used to choose an option inside a DropDown?

Also is it possible to do it like mentioned below

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@placeholder='Select Quota']").click()

followed by something else?

Comment: I've used `send_keys` before to select an option in a drop down.

Comment: send keys followed by enter?

Answer (score 0):

This drop down has been construct using select and options tags. So select class should work.

You can try with this code :

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select.ng-tns-c13-11"))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('C')
```

Imports you will have to do :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

Comment: updated the answer with import , if in case you were facing any issue.

Comment: says element is currently not visible and cannot be manipulated

Comment: Then use wait.until(EC.visibilty_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR(“select.ng-tns-c13-11”))) in Select()

Comment: no!
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select.ng-tns-c13-11"))-->works fine
But,select.selct_by_visible_text('C') is where the exception occurs

Comment: the you can wait for some time and then execute `select.select_by_visible_text('C')`

Answer (score 0):

As the `<select>` element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `<select>` *element to be clickable* and utilizing the `Select` class you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
# other lines of code
mySelect = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibilty_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[contains(@class,'ng-tns-') and @aria-label='A']"))))
# select by value
mySelect.select_by_value("LD")
```

Comment: Try out the updated answer and let me know the status

Answer (score 0):

Just need to wait for the LD element to be clickable first, like so...

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@value='LD']")))
```